# 97 Chevy Tahoe 4X4

Tags: chevrolet, starter, tahoe

does a starter have to be grounded to the negative terminal or to the frame? My new starter(Diagonal starter bolt holes)(97 chevy tahoe 4x4) has a bolt with a nut on the top back side of the starter by itself and im not sure what goes there looks to me as if a ground would go there? and it also has a mega fuse 175A by the radiator cover and i dont think its hooked up correctly. so from the looks of it that apparently is what gives my whole truck power. because I have NO Power at all whats so ever, or somethings not hooked up right, its a customers truck. ALl the fuses in the fuse boxs under and inner are good as far as I know. i checked them yesterday. My relays are all good . I turn the igntion switch it doesn;t make any noise no chime no nothing. even with jumper cables thinking maybe a dead battery,, new battery in as well. nothing.. please explain this to me cause somethings not making sense, and im really sick of looking at it!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

You should have two connections to the starter. The large pole on the solenoid is the direct power cable from the battery. The other smaller wire is the ignition wire (it should be a purple wire). When you turn the key, power is provided here to kick the solenoid in, which transfers power down to the starter motor. The starter itself is grounded through the engine by bolting it to it, so no ground wire is directly attached to the starter. The engine should have a ground strap to the body. There will most likely be other wires at the large solenoid lug where you attach the main battery cable. These wires will be where the rest of the vehicle gets its power from. You can tell which ones go there because they'll have the larger diameter connector on them, but won't be going to the battery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That model comes with a heat shield on the starter from the factory , someone may have removed it and it’s what the shield would bolt to. There is a breaded ground cable in the area where the wires from starter go up into a protective tube about 6” from the starter itself. I belive that ground goes from the body to engine block.